# Find the standard matrix representation of $T(x,y) = (y,x,x-y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the standard matrix representation of $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(x,y) = (y, x, x-y)$.

How do I do this problem?

I know that a function that is a linear transformation satisfies

1) $T(v+u) = T(v) + T(u)$

2) $T(cu) = cT(u)$, for any scalar $c$.

How do I find the standard matrix?

Comment: put the images of the basis vectors in columns

Comment: You need to have a basis for both $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ first.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305884/265466) and many others. Might it be time to add this to the [List of generalizations of common questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions), not that anyone ever looks there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to find a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}\\a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}\end{bmatrix}$ such that

$\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}\\a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}y\\x\\x-y\end{bmatrix}$

Well... let's look at this.  What does it mean for the resulting first row of the product to be equal to the first row of the desired result?

> It means that $a_{1,1}x + a_{1,2}y = y$ for all $x,y$.

Clearly, that happens precisely when:

> $a_{1,1}=0$ and $a_{1,2}=1$

Indeed, once you see what is going on you should be able to do this quite quickly.

> Notice that $\begin{bmatrix}y\\x\\x-y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0x+1y\\1x+0y\\1x-1y\end{bmatrix}$... now, look at the coefficients

Comment: Awww I see. I was very close to getting this on my scratch pad. What threw me off was the fact that T(x,y) had 3 components. So if I needed to find the matrix transformation of the same vector but w.r.t a basis {(1,1),(-1,1)} i am assuming it would be a similar process?

Comment: @Aeryes similar process, yes.  Try to figure it out on your own.  Write out what it would mean first and see if you can relate that to a problem you've already seen solved.  The new problem may have more flavor, but if you can chew and swallow it should be able to be digested all the same.  A general tip might be to look at what happens to each of the basis vectors one at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the help and your time :) Its very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The standard matrix has columns that are the images of the vectors of the standard basis
 $$
T \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} \Bigg)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},  
\qquad
T \Bigg (\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix} \Bigg)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

So the standard matrix is

> $$\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\ 1& 0\\1& -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

You put the images of the basis vectors in columns.

The standard basis vectors $(1,0)\mapsto(0,1,1)$ and $(0,1)\mapsto(1,0,-1)$.

Therefore, the standard matrix is $\pmatrix{0&&1\\1&&0\\1&&-1}$.

You can check that $\pmatrix{0&&1\\1&&0\\1&&-1}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{y\\x\\x-y}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was clear and concise. I asked someone else above if it would be a similar approach if I had to find the standard representation w.r.t a basis {(1,1),(-1,1)} for this same vector.

Comment: Yes, but note that, to determine a matrix representation of a linear transformation, you need a basis for the domain and a basis for the range

Comment: I was told that B={(1,1),(-1,1)} and {e1,e2,e3} are the bases used on R2 and R3.

Comment: Then you would put the images of the vectors in $B$ in the columns

Comment: But how would (1,1) map to the column if there is 1x and 1y?

Comment: $T(1,1)=(1,1,0)$

Comment: So after I find my matrix how do I then use that matrix to find T(3,-2)?

Comment: $(3,-2)=\frac12(1,1)-\frac52(-1,1)$, so multiply the matrix with images of $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ as columns by $\pmatrix{\frac12\\-\frac52}$

Comment: So multiply 1/2 by the first column and -5/2 by the second

Answer (score 0):

If by the "standard matrix representation", you meant the matrix of $T$ w.r.t the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then just apply $T$ to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and write the image as a linear combination of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.